# Help solving $a\lambda^d + b\lambda^e + c\lambda^f = abc$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve the below (it's part of a bigger problem) but I just don't know the direction I should follow... any tips for me?

$a\lambda^d + b\lambda^e + c\lambda^f = abc$

a,b,c,d,e,f are positive real numbers, I'm trying to solve for $\lambda$. If it can only be solved subjective to constrains please do point them out, I may be able to change the problem a bit.

Thanks!

Comment: Presumably, $d, e, f$ are integers, otherwise this is not a polynomial in $\lambda$, right?

Comment: I probably put the question in the wrong tag... sorry!

Comment: What is the bigger problem you are trying to solve? Maybe it doesn't have to get to this point?